# Highlight cells if found

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid that outputs 90 rows after being bound to a datatable. The rows values are the 1-90 ascending.

What I want to achieve:

If the number is found in an array/range/list of numbers then highlight it green.

I have managed to get it to highlight the cell based on 1 value, but I want to highlight several cells if they are found in the range.

```
<DataGrid Name="grid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="300" Width="900"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" RowHeight="40">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="BackgroundColourStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Number}" 
            ElementStyle="{StaticResource BackgroundColourStyle}" MinWidth="40">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGrid.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>                    
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </DataGrid.ItemsPanel>
        </DataGrid>
```

you can see I have a trigger property of the value 1. This works fine, but as above, how do I change this so if a cell is in the range set in c# in backend then highlight it green.

binding to datatable:

```
calledGrid.DataContext = calledNumbers.DefaultView;
```

The actual making of the datatable:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("myDS");
            this.bingoCalls(dataSet);
            DataTable numbersTable = new DataTable("Numbers");
            numbersTable.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(Int32));

            for (int i = 1; i < 91; i++)
            {
                numbersTable.Rows.Add(i);
            }
            dataSet.Tables.Add(numbersTable);
```

Thanks for any help guys. If you need any more info or I have been to vague or unclear about anything please do ask and i will do my best to respond ASAP. Also please excuse any ignorance I may have, I am very new to wpf. I will do my best.

Comment: Difficult without knowing more about the environment around that. How is this search done for example. I would trigger the search in the view model for that datagrid, which just sets a value on each ViewModel (IsHighlighted for example) and would have one simple trigger in xaml. But it really depends on the rest of your code.

Comment: @Ryan Murphy - You can achieve that using `IMultiValueConverter`. I have added an answer. See if that helps..!!

Comment: Since this is WPF, I would actually try to add an `IsGreen` property (or something named like that which makes sense according to your business logic) to your data row object that is populated with `true`/`false`, and just have your UI reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that using `IMultiValueConverter` which will return true if Text lies within the range otherwise return false. `Based on the value returned by converter, change background color`.

Pass three parameters to converter:

1. Actual Text value.
2. Minimum value.
3. Maximum value.

**Converter**

```
public class ItemExistInRangeConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool itemsExistInRange = false;
        if (values.Length == 3)
        {
            int outputValue = int.MinValue;
            if (Int32.TryParse(values[0].ToString(), out outputValue))
            {
                int minValue = (int)values[1];
                int maxValue = (int)values[2];
                itemsExistInRange = minValue <= outputValue
                                     && outputValue <= maxValue;
            }
        }
        return itemsExistInRange;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes,
                                object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <local:ItemExistInRangeConverter x:Key="ItemExistInRangeConverter"/>
    <sys:Int32 x:Key="MinimumValue">1</sys:Int32>
    <sys:Int32 x:Key="MaximumValue">50</sys:Int32>
    <Style x:Key="BackgroundColourStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
       <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Value="True">
             <DataTrigger.Binding>
                 <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ItemExistInRangeConverter}">
                     <Binding Path="Text" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                     <Binding Source="{StaticResource MinimumValue}"/>
                     <Binding Source="{StaticResource MaximumValue}"/>
                 </MultiBinding>
             </DataTrigger.Binding>
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Make sure you add corresponding namespace at root level:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NamespaceOfConverter"
// Replace NamespaceOfConverter with namespace where converter resides.
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

---

**UPDATE** (In case want to find item in an array of numbers)

*Assuming your array of numbers property exist in code behind or view model class.*

First of all you need to `set ItemsSource of DataGrid to DataTable` instead of DataContext.

Second, `set DataContext of DataGrid to this from code behind or an instance of viewModel class`.

Also, to refresh GUI your class should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface.

Now, assume you have a property say:

```
public int[] RangeNumbers { get; set; }
```

By default it will contain list of numbers which you want to highlight.

XAML will look like this:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <local:ItemExistInRangeConverter x:Key="ItemExistInRangeConverter"/>
       <Style x:Key="BackgroundColourStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
           <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Value="True">
                 <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ItemExistInRangeConverter}">
                       <Binding Path="Text" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                       <Binding Path="DataContext.RangeNumbers" 
                                RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                  AncestorType=DataGrid}"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                 </DataTrigger.Binding>
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Converter code:

```
public class ItemExistInRangeConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool itemsExistInRange = false;
        if (values.Length == 2)
        {
            int outputValue = int.MinValue;
            int[] rangeNumbers = (int[])values[1];
            if (rangeNumbers != null && 
                Int32.TryParse(values[0].ToString(), out outputValue))
            {
                itemsExistInRange = rangeNumbers.Contains(outputValue);
            }
        }
        return itemsExistInRange;
     }

     public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes,
                                 object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
}
```

Now, items will be highlighted based on initial numbers in `RangeNumbers`. But suppose you update array afterwards, you need to raise property changed event so that GUI gets refreshed something like this:

```
RangeNumbers = new int[] { 23, 45, 47, 69 };
OnPropertyChanged("RangeNumbers");
```

Comment: Does the xaml snippet replace my datagrid or does it go underneath it?

Comment: Replace your `DataGrid.Resources` section with my xaml snippet of `DataGrid.Resources`.

Comment: So this does it for value betweeen the ranges, but what about if a number is in an array or something like in the question?

Comment: You can pass `Range as one of the bindings` to converter and modify `Converter` code to check in that array passed. Let me know in case you need some help in that.

Comment: Ok thanks. I would like to give it a go first, and will post an update tomorrow once i have tried tonight. thanks again.

Comment: Hi, I might need your assistance further on this, what i am working with is not a range. What I have is an array, which at first is empty, but during user actions it populates. If a number at any point is in that list then the number goes green.

Comment: Please check the updated answer and see if that works for you.

Comment: Is 'set ItemsSource of DataGrid to DataTable' achieved by: grid.DataContext = numbersTable.DefaultView;

Comment: Ya just do this way `grid.ItemsSource = numbersTable.DefaultView`.

Comment: So I have `public int[] RangeNumbers { get; set; }` in my class, but then you say to include: `RangeNumbers = new int[] { 23, 45, 47, 69 };
OnPropertyChanged("RangeNumbers");`? when i put onpropertychanged anywhere it doesnt havea return type.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43949/discussion-between-ryan-murphy-and-rohit-vats)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example how to accomplish this by using MVVM pattern (which would also work if any number is edited / changed or criteria for highlighting changes) and Style Setter with MultiBinding:

**MainWindowModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    class MainWindowModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private DataTable numbersTable;
        private Predicate<int> highlightCriteria;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public DataTable NumbersTable
        {
            get { return this.numbersTable; }
            set { this.SetValue(ref this.numbersTable, value, "NumbersTable"); }
        }

        public Predicate<int> HighlightCriteria
        {
            get { return this.highlightCriteria; }
            set { this.SetValue(ref this.highlightCriteria, value, "HighlightCriteria"); }
        }

        public MainWindowModel()
        {
            this.NumbersTable = new DataTable("Numbers")
            {
                Columns = 
                {
                    { "Number", typeof(int) }
                },
            };

            for (int i = 1; i < 91; i++)
                this.NumbersTable.Rows.Add(i);

            // By default only numbers larger than 10 and lower than 50 will be highlighted.
            this.HighlightCriteria = num => num > 10 && num < 50;
        }

        protected void SetValue<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
        {
            if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            {
                field = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

**NumberTextToBackgroundConverter.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    class NumberTextToBackgroundConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public static readonly IMultiValueConverter Instance = new NumberTextToBackgroundConverter();

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int number;
            var numberText = values[0] as string;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(numberText) && int.TryParse(numberText, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out number))
            {
                var highlightCriteria = values[1] as Predicate<int>;
                if (highlightCriteria != null && highlightCriteria(number))
                    return Brushes.LightGreen;
            }

            return Brushes.Transparent;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding NumbersTable}">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{x:Static local:NumberTextToBackgroundConverter.Instance}">
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Content.Text"/>
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}" Path="DataContext.HighlightCriteria"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for a detailed code snippets, looks great, problem is I dont understand most of the changes you have made. It seems to totally change my code because maybe you suggest this is a much better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a conditional converter. See [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a8ad8c14-95aa-4ed4-b806-d0ae874a8d26/conditional-triggers?forum=wpf).

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing is like this:

Suppose you are binding the rows to a property called Items, which is a List of something. You should create a property like "IsHighlighted" like had been suggested, and your code should set it as true or false depending on the user input.

Then, to actually highlight the row, you should attach an Event of LoadingRow in the DataGrid, like:

```
MyDataGrid.LoadingRow
  += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRowEventArgs>(myMethod);
```

then in myMethod do something like this:

```
void myMethod(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
        RowClass item = (RowClass)e.Row.Item;
        if (item.IsHighlighted)
        {
            e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        }
        else
        {
            e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would throw this option in and might be even more simple... You already have a data table of a column with rows 1-90.  Why not add another column to the datatable as a "ShowColor" column.  Blast through the list once for whatever condition on all rows and have the background color bound to that of the "ShowColor".  Then, no special "converters" are required.

Also, you refer to wanting to color many cells, and that point is a little vague.  Do you mean on a single row that may be exposing 10 columns, you want the cells in row 1, columns 1, 2, 5, 8, 10 to be shown in green (not probable)?  Or... for the ENTIRE Row 1 that qualified the condition, you want ALL columns for that row to be background of green.  Two completely different answers would come out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really a WPF programmer but the example below should be readily convertible because the concepts are the same as Windows Forms to do what you need done. The following example accomplishes the following at startup:

1. Creates a class-level `DataSet` named `m_dataSet`.
2. Adds a two column `DataTable` called `Numbers` to the `DataSet` and loads it with sample data.

   - The columns are named `Value` and `Active`.
   - The data types are `int` and `bool` respectively.
3. Assigns the `Numbers` table as the `DataSource` of the `DataGridView` control. This causes the control to automatically add both columns from the `Numbers` table. So afterwards, the value of the `dataGridView1.Columns["Active"].Visible` property gets set to false. This lets the `Numbers` table be bound to the `DataGridView` control without having hidden columns shown to the user. The number of columns that gets shown is up to you.
4. Creates event handlers for:

   - `dataGridView1_CellClick` - This just provides an easy way to select random cells and prove the cell `BackColor` selection change. This is where the "Active" column in the data source toggles between true and false.
   - `dataGridView1_CellFormatting` - This is thrown (in Windows Forms anyhow) every time a cell requires formatting for display. By handling this event to assign the `Cell.BackColor`, we don't have to iterate through every row to refresh colors because Windows is already doing that for any invalidated cells. Were updateing the `BackColor` immediately bofore the cell is painted. It works equally well when manually calling `Invalidate` or, when incidental repaint events happen that you didn't cause.
   - `button1_Click` - Finally, it shows how to clear all of the selected items in the `DataGridView` control.

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadGridData();
    }

    private DataSet m_dataSet = new DataSet("myDS");

    private void LoadGridData() {

        //--------------------------------------------------
        // Build Numbers Table
        //--------------------------------------------------
        DataTable numbersTable = new DataTable("Numbers");

        numbersTable.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(Int32));
        numbersTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(
            "Active", 
            typeof(bool)) { 
            DefaultValue = false 
        });

        for (int i = 1; i < 91; i++) {
            numbersTable.Rows.Add(i);
        }

        m_dataSet.Tables.Add(numbersTable);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = m_dataSet.Tables["Numbers"];
        dataGridView1.Columns["Active"].Visible = false;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // Reset all Active settings to false.
        foreach (DataRow row in m_dataSet.Tables["Numbers"].Rows) {
            row["Active"] = false;
        }

        dataGridView1.Invalidate();
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {

        if (e.RowIndex > -1 && e.ColumnIndex == 0) {
            int cellValue = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;

            //---------------------------------------------------
            // Create a query that selects any rows that have the 
            // cellValue in the "Value" field. This will only return 
            // one row as long as long as you Numbers table stays
            // unique. You have to query for the number because 
            // e.RowIndex returns the wrong row when sorted descending.
            //---------------------------------------------------
            var query = 
                m_dataSet.Tables["Numbers"].AsEnumerable()
                .Where(row => row.Field<int>("Value") == cellValue);

            // Update Active field
            foreach(var row in query)
                row["Active"] = (bool)row["Active"] == false;
        }

        // Take focus off the control to avoid dark blue 
        // selection color. -- could also set default backcolor
        // to forecolor to create the obvious selection immediately
        //  when a cell gets clicked.
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e) {
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)dataGridView1.Rows[0].DataBoundItem;

        //---------------------------------------------------
        // Set the BackColor of the cell based on the underlying 
        // data's Active setting.
        //---------------------------------------------------
        if (e.RowIndex < m_dataSet.Tables["Numbers"].Rows.Count) {
            if ((bool)drv.DataView[e.RowIndex]["Active"] == true)
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.PowderBlue;
            else
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
        }
    }
```

Here is what the output looks like in Windows Forms. I hope this answer helps you to solve your problem. Take care.

[image]

Also from what I've read, you can host Windows Forms controls in WPF apps. The DataGridView has significant performance advantages of the the DataGrid control. Especially with large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

This should be simple enough if you just use a `DataTrigger`.  Use an `IValueConverter` to return a true/false value based on the row.  You can either hard-code the list/range of included numbers in the converter, or pass them in from the XAML as a parameter:

```
public class HighlightConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private int[] _highlightedNumbers = { 1, 5, 12, 15 };

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value as int? == null)
            return false;

        // get the highlighted numbers, either hard-coded locally, or passed in as the ConverterParameter
        int[] highlightedNumbers;
        var numbersCsv = parameter as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(numbersCsv))
            highlightedNumbers = numbersCsv.Split(',').Select(item => int.Parse(item.Trim())).ToArray();
        else
            highlightedNumbers = _highlightedNumbers;

        return highlightedNumbers.Contains((int)value) ? true : false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now simply apply a `DataTrigger`, based on the row value, using this converter to check for the highlight condition:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
     <my:HighlightConverter x:Key="my:HighlightConverter" />
     <Style x:Key="BackgroundColourStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
         <Style.Triggers>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource my:HighlightConverter},ConverterParameter='1,5,12,15'}" Value="True">
                 <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
             </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

---

**Edit (an alternative)**

The above will work if you know the list of highlighted numbers at compile time.  Alternatively, if the list is based on another runtime value, then you will need a `MultiBinding`.  The idea is similar, but this time the converter will apply two values: the allowed list, and the row value itself:

```
public class HighlightConverter : IValueConverter, IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var includedNumbers = values[0] as int[];
        if (includedNumbers == null || values[1] as int? == null)
            return false;
        return includedNumbers.Contains((int)values[1]);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now you just have to bind to the property that contains the list of highlighted numbers.  Let's say your current Window's DataContext is a viewmodel with an `int[] HighlightedNumbers` property.  Then, you could use a `RelativeSource` binding.  The result would look something like this:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <converter:HighlightConverter x:Key="HighlightConverter" />
    <Style x:Key="BackgroundColourStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource HighlightConverter}">
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}" Path="DataContext.HighlightedNumbers" />
                        <Binding />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer mate, appreciated. I am trying this now and hope to give you feedback by tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Only problem I can see with this initially is that i would be setting  'includedNumbers' outside of the HighlightConverter class.

Comment: @RyanMurphy is it a constant value for the application lifetime?  If so, then maybe set it on application startup?  Otherwise, if it changes, you'd probably want the multi-binding.